# COM/LPT/USB порты и Java

Tags: java, usb, com-порт, lpt

Есть задачка - кроссплатформенно работать с устройствами по соответствующим портам ( COM/LPT/USB )

Наткнулся на Java Communication API, но написано что "Oracle no longer support this API for any Windows platform".
Что использовать и какие варианты решения вопроса есть?

Comment: для Windows написать dll  с нативным кодом. Для всех остальных судя по всему уже есть.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поковыряться с [JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/)

Comment: А без ковыряния готовых библиотек нету?

Comment: Так напишите библиотеку на С++, используя любую известную библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно, пакеты `javax.comm.*` поддерживаются только для Linux/Sparc. Под Windows можно попробовать коммерческие библиотеки, например [jComm](http://www.icaste.com/)